# How to write an if formula in notion with multiple conditions

Tags: formula, notion

I have a property called "No PT/NT" when the requirements are met it spits out "Single Task"

if "No PT/TA" = "Single Task" I would like it to read as " Action"

I would like to incorporate it into the following formula:

if(prop("Task After Report") < 1, " Action", " Waiting")

I'm stuck on how to combine this formula

Answer (score 0):

If you want to first check if "No PT/TA" = "Single Task" (true then " Action") and if it's not true check `if(prop("Task After Report") < 1, " Action", " Waiting")`.

Do it like this:

```
if(contains(prop("No PT/TA"), "Single Task")," Action", if(prop("Task After Report") > 1, " Action", " Waiting"))
```